# Extract Date from epoch in NiFi

Tags: regex, apache, elasticsearch, kibana, apache-nifi

I have a CSV file with an attribute having epoch values like '1517334599.906'.

I want to convert/update the Epoch values into ISO timestamp 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' via NiFi.

That conversion is for Kibana to recognize the field as Timestamp. Is there a way to do this? If there is can anyone help me with the configuration?

Comment: Is the epoch value in a field of the csv entry, or is it in a flow file attribute?

Comment: @BryanBende The Epoch values are in field of CSV entry. Is there a way I can make the field as part of flow file attribute to perform operations? Right now no transformation is working on any field. How can i make the fields attribute of flow file? TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using NiFi's record capabilities you can use UpdateRecord with a CsvReader and CsvWriter.

See the "format" function in expression language for converting an epoch to a date string:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format

In UpdateRecord you would do something like:

```
/eventDate = ${field.value:format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}
```

This says take the value of /eventDate (change this to your field name) and set the value of that field to the result of the format function on the right.

The only thing I am not sure about is whether an epoch can have a decimal portion as shown in your example. I would expect it to be converted to a long which would be a whole number.

Comment: Works fine without the '.' part. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did not try it myself, but someone gave me this feedback: the link was saying to use record path value
but after reading the description I see that literal value is picking up the field.value
so after changing to literal value in the update Atrribute it worked fine

Comment: I have a similar scenario I have a epoch value in my timestamp field in csv file, I need to convert to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format, I tried above solution didn't work. Do i need to update AvroSchema or anything ?

Also the datatype of the field in avroschema is something like below



{"name":"dob","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]


@Shrads